# Using Java-script to write a certain function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flip

http://jsfiddle.net/cjLm77ek/

In this example here, I want to add something to the java script code so that when I re-click the flip button again, it flips back to the original form.
How should I do that? What should I add to the java script code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flip_content").click(function() {
        $("#f1_card").css("transform", "rotateX(180deg)");
        $("#f1_card").css("box-shadow", "-5px 5px 5px #aaa");
    });
});
```

Comment: try to understand what the code does. If you want to flip back, do the opposite: rotate to 0 degrees and clear the box shadow. See http://jsfiddle.net/3rf8kdyn/ and if you want to that with a single button, then the code has to remember the state.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest one is to toggle a class:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#flip_content").click(function() {
        $("#f1_card").toggleClass('flip');        
    });

});
```

```css
#f1_container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 450px;
    height: 281px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
    perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}

/* disable hover change
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
*/

.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
    display: block;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #aaa;
}

.flip {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="f1_container">
    <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
        <div class="front face">lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">
            <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
            <p>Any content can go here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="flip_content">Flip</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using javascript where you should just use css for the transition and javascript to trigger the animation.

Now all javascript is responsible for is toggling a class on the card element and the browser handles the rest.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#flip_content").click(function() {
    $("#f1_card").toggleClass('rotated')
  })
})
```

```css
#flip_content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#f1_card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  transition: 1s all;
}
#f1_card.rotated {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip_content">
  <div id="f1_card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to click on a button, and have another element flip instead, so I thought Java-script was the right choice. Can I do that with CSS?

Comment: Yes. This code decouples the element that flips to the element that was clicked. You would just need to change the selector in the click callback that toggles the class. `$("#some_selector").toggleClass('rotated')`